# Ошибка при открытии файлы .jsx django

Tags: django, reactjs, frontend, django-rest-framework, backend

Делаю сайт на react с back-end на django. Мне нужно было запустить мой yarn. Сделал по [гайду](https://github.com/epineda/django-yarn/blob/master/README.md) на django-yarn, но при запуске выскакивает ошибка (*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. react django*):
[image: текст ошибки]

Мой код settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'yarn.finders.YarnFinder',
)

YARN_ROOT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'yarn')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Моя иерархия файлов:

[image: иерархия папок]

Вкладка network браузера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данная ошибка появляется в браузере или где? Если в браузере, то посмотрите, как подключены js файлы и во вкладке network(консоли разработчика) какие заголовки присылаются. Такое ощущение, что main.jsx вам приходит "как есть" без компиляции в js код и с заголовком, то это обычный текст

Comment: а что в файле src/main.jsx ? и vite.config.js что-нибудь меняли?

Comment: @SwaD прикрепил network в дополнение к вопросу

Comment: @Kjuri всё стандартно. В main.jsx только импорты react и reactdom, функция createroot, которая возвращает заголовок. config никак не менял

Comment: Порядок в `STATICFILES_FINDERS` имеет значение, попробуйте переместить `'yarn.finders.YarnFinder'` в самое начало

Comment: (а вообще для меня весь этот django-yarn выглядит как страшный костыль, который лучше не использовать)

Comment: @andreymal а что использовать тогда? Просто я ещё джун, который ещё даже онлайн курс не закончил, и не очень понимаю. Что-то мне не помог ваш способ...

Comment: На стороне Django — ничего, потому что зачем? Если вы хотите, чтобы Django был чисто бэкендом — значит по-хорошему в нём не должно быть ничего про фронтенд. А вашу фронтенд-сборку с реактом раздавайте отдельно через какой-нибудь nginx или типа того

Comment: (и да, по такой логике `templates/index.html` тоже должен отсутствовать, потому что он должен быть внутри фронтенд-сборки)

Comment: Согласен с andreymal, что фронт нужно собрать отдельным проектом, тем более, что реакт нуждается в компиляции(можно конечно в браузере компилировать, но не рекомндую).